# Can we use "shot" for "serum"?

Tags: word-request, phrase-request

I was in the hospital the other day. A doctor prescribed me serum. How could I say this? Can I use "shot"? Like "I got a shot yesterday"?

And what can a nurse say when they do this to you? "I (the nurse) give him (a patient) a shot/serum"?

I don't know if you use serum in this situation so this picture is also attached to prevent any ambiguity about what I meant by serum.

[image]

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The picture is of someone "getting an IV".  A nurse would "administer an IV" or simply "give an IV".

(On TV a doctor might yell at a nurse to, "Start an IV stat!" or, "Get an IV started with 250 milligrams of isopropylwhambamthankyoumamamine stat!" -- but the few times I've been witness to actual real life emergency rooms, they never said anything like that.)

> I went into the emergency room and they found my electrolytes were really low, so they gave me an IV.
>
> While my father was in the hospital they administered all his medications through an IV.

"IV" is short for ["intravenous drip"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intravenous_therapy), but you hear the phrase all the time on television so many people will know what "IV" means.

Comment: In AusEng I think people are more likely to call it a "drip" than an "IV".

Comment: @curiousdannii this is why I said [we need more Aussies on here](http://meta.ell.stackexchange.com/questions/3389/how-come-i-never-see-any-aussies-on-here)!

Comment: @Andrew thanks for the answer. you used a long interesting phrase here. what's that supposed to mean?  ''wham bam thank you mam' stat''

Comment: @MasihK it's from a [classic rock song "Suffragette City"](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zLnPd7lzT4g) by the recently deceased David Bowie.  I have no idea *exactly* what it means in that song but here I threw it in as a kind of a joke -- in medical dramas on TV, the actors often say these long medical terms which are probably accurate but which the audience might not know are accurate.  So they could say *any* nonsense and the audience wouldn't care.

Comment: "Stat" is a medical term which means "right away!".  Again you hear it yelled a lot on medical dramas, but not so much when I worked in a hospital (although they do write it on medical orders).

Answer (score 9):

A "shot" would be typically used to refer to a syringe, which is a handheld needle of some kind. "Serum" is a liquid component of blood.

What you have pictured there is an "intravenous drip", presumably full of blood plasma or "serum" to replace lost fluid. While both a "shot" and an "intravenous drip" or "IV" both use a needle, the words are not used interchangeably.

Comment: A 'serum' may be the content of the IV or of the shot.  Allergy shots are often a 'serum'.  
The picture is not a shot, it is an IV, as you state.

Answer (score 3):

Yes you can use the term

> **shot** *(in the arm)*

for a serum or vaccine which is administered using a needle and syringe either under your skin *subcutaneous (sub-Q)* or *intramuscular (IM)*.

It can also be called a

> **jab**

[image]

Answer (score 2):

A more formal term for a “shot” is ***injection***.

> [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/injection):
>
>   something (as a medication) that is
>   [*injected*](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/injected)
>     [***inject***](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/inject)
>     :
>       to force a fluid into (as for medical purposes)
>       <
>       *inject*
>       a drug into the bloodstream>
>
> [Macmillan Dictionary](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/us/dictionary/american/injection):
>
>   a drug or another substance that is injected into your body
>   *He needs a daily injection of insulin.*
>
> [Medical dictionary (thefreedictionary.com)](http://medical-dictionary.thefreedictionary.com/injection):
>
> - the forcing of a liquid into a part, …
>
>   a substance so forced or administered;
>     in pharmacy, a solution of a medicament suitable for injection.
>        ︙

This refers to the use of a handheld hypodermic needle:

[image: hypodermic needle]
          <sup>[Original image source: http://dosagemayvary.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/06/162223080.0.jpg ]</sup>

containing some sort of liquid drug or medicine,
being manually inserted into a patient’s body —
usually (but not always) into the arm:

[image: injection into arm]
          <sup>[Original image source: http://www.proprofs.com/flashcards/upload/q10231646.jpg ]</sup>

The word “hypodermic” is formed from *hypo* + *dermic*. 
“Hypo” means *under*, and “dermic” refers to *skin*.

And yes, you can use the word “shot”
as in “I got a shot yesterday” and “the nurse gave the patient a shot” —
if that’s what happened (but not for your picture).