# To be on a drip in the hospital

Tags: sentence-meaning, idioms

How would it be possible to indicate you have passed 2 days in the hospital and in those days they had gave me an IV and in a nonstop manner? Does the sentence below make any sense to you:

> - I **was on a drip** at the hospital for 2 days.

This is where I found the term [on a drip](http://dictionary.reverso.net/english-cobuild/to%20be%20put%20on%20a%20drip)

I didn't find any reliable source which can acknowledge the meaning. I don't remember when or when, but once I heard or read it somewhere and took it down to a piece of paper up to know. Asking this question I was going to make sure if the term works in this sense and I had got the meaning correctly or not.

I had a look on the similar [thread](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/114724/can-we-use-shot-for-serum), but there was no any indication to the idiom I was looking for. You hit 5 hits when you search the word "drip", but there is no similar idiom like what I was looking for. I mean: "to be on a drip"!

Comment: It is fine -- both grammatical and colloquial.

Comment: What is the problem with the linked to source? It includes the example in exactly the context your want.

Comment: Do you have access to Google Ngram?  https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=on+a+drip&year_start=1900&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Con%20a%20drip%3B%2Cc0

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?q=%22on%20a%20drip%22&tbm=bks&lr=lang_en

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can we use "shot" for "serum"?](http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/114724/can-we-use-shot-for-serum)

Comment: @TRomano yes, I have, but the problem is that I didn't find any description showing that the idiom is indicative of the meaning in my question at time. Perhaps my literacy doesn't suffice to understand well yet. Thank you for being of help. :)

Comment: Of course you do find such descriptions, @A-friend.  Click on the link at the bottom for attestations. The contexts clearly show that the phrase means what you think it means.  I've included the link above.

Comment: If by the attestation you mean the link of the thread **("Can we use “shot” for “serum”?)**, then may I ask you to copy and past the explanation about the idiom "to be on a drip" here as a new comment @TRomano. Please. :)

Comment: @A-friend. You're confusing my comment with Andrew's.  By **attestations**, I mean the *dozens* of texts in which the phrase **on a drip** appears, clearly in contexts where it means "to be connected to an intravenous line". Excerpts from those texts  are given when you click on one of the links at the bottom of the Ngram graph.  This is a tool you should learn how to use, since it can answer many of your questions.

Comment: @TRomano you're right. I have to learn how to use it in a better way.  It was really helpful.Thank you again for being of help. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As a medical student / former nurse, that makes perfect sense to me. I will use that expression too, though depending on who I am talking to I may prefer to say:

- I have received parenteral rehydration for two days at the hospital
- They pumped me full of water at the hospital for two whole days
- I have been given 2L of NaCl during the last 48 hours at the hospital

English is a language spoken by a very large group of people and there is hardly any expression that 100% of speakers will know before you say it. Being on a drip at the hospital is quite easy to understand if you have ever seen an intravenous line dripping next to a patient.

[image: A infusion bag with a drip module attached to it to verify the correct speed of flow]